# change database migrations from sqlalchemy-migrate to Flask-Migrate

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, data-migration, alembic, flask-migrate

I have an web app base on [miguel flask tutorial](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database)

So I use sqlalchemy-migrate for database and Now I should Use **Alembic** in migration How can I do the configuration? is there any way that I can change from sqlalchemy-migrate to  Flask-Migrate?(coz my app is complete and do it again is so much work again) Thanx

> db_migrate.py :

```
#!flask/bin/python
import imp
from migrate.versioning import api
from app import db
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
migration = SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO + '/versions/%03d_migration.py' % (api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO) + 1)
tmp_module = imp.new_module('old_model')
old_model = api.create_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
exec old_model in tmp_module.__dict__
script = api.make_update_script_for_model(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, tmp_module.meta, db.metadata)
open(migration, "wt").write(script)
api.upgrade(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
print 'New migration saved as ' + migration
print 'Current database version: ' + str(api.db_version(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three possible ways to handle this, two are relatively easy, but the last is pretty laborious:

#### 1. Only track future migrations with Flask-Migrate

This is the easiest, but less interesting. Just install and setup Flask-Migrate as you would for a new project, and the next time you need to migrate, use this instead of sqlalchemy-migrate.

The drawback is that the current state of the migration is not recorded by Alembic, only the migrations you apply in the future are.

#### 2. Track the current state of the database as a single initial migration

This improves on the previous method and makes Flask-Migrate's repository complete, but all the migrations that you have in sqlalchemy-migrate are collapsed into a single migration for Alembic.

The process is as follows:

- Create the Flask-Migrate repository
- Backup the data in your database, if you care (you will lose it in your next step!)
- Using the `db_downgrade.py` script from the tutorial, set your database to version 0 (the empty database).
- Generate a migration with Flask-Migrate. This migration will include all the database changes until your current version.
- Restore the data to your database.
- Apply future migrations with Flask-Migrate normally. You can delete the sqlalchemy-migrate repository, as all the database changes are now in Alembic.

#### 3. Transfer the entire migration history to Flask-Migrate

This is the most complex of the solutions, as it requires every single migration you have in sqlalchemy-migrate to be transferred individually to Alembic.

The process is as follows:

- Create the Flask-Migrate repository
- Backup the data in your database, if you care (you will lose it in your next step!)
- Using the `db_downgrade.py` script from the tutorial, set your database to version 0 (the empty database). Or if it is easier, just delete all the tables in the database manually.
- Assuming you have your application on source control, checkout the version of code that matches your first database migration.
- Generate a migration with Flask-Migrate. This migration will be identical to your first sqlalchemy-migrate migration.
- Checkout the version of code that matches the second sqlalchemy-migrate migration.
- Generate a second migration with Flask-Migrate. This migration will be identical to your second sqlalchemy-migrate migration.
- Continue like this until you reach the current version of code and the last database migration.
- Restore the data to your database.
- Apply future migrations with Flask-Migrate normally. You can delete the sqlalchemy-migrate repository, as all the database changes are now in Alembic.

If you need a recommendation, I think #2 is the best option in most cases. I would only go through the pain of #3 if I expected I would need to downgrade my database to specific migrations in the history.

Comment: Thnx for ur reply, But unfortunately I am kinda new and don't know how to backup data or restore them is there an special command line or tutorial that or can you explain it in more detail @Miguel

Comment: This is database dependent. What kind of database do you have?